# How to remove button in index.html using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, navbar

I have a **navigation-bar** that I set to change styles when the width of the page is less than **1180 pixels**. I was able to successfully apply the styles when the break-point of the page width changes, however, it won't apply unless I **reload** the page.

```
const toggleMenu = document.querySelector('.toggle-menu');

// Hide Hamburger Menu when less than 1180px in width

if(window.innerWidth >= '1180') {
    toggleMenu.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    window.location.reload();
};
if(window.innerWidth <= '1180'){
    toggleMenu.style.visibility = 'visible';
    window.location.reload();
};
```

So, I tried using **`window.location.reload()`** and it worked! It removes `<button class='toggle-menu'></button>` and adds it again when the break-point changes, but it keeps reloading the page over and over again.

How can I get the page to **reload** just **once**, when the width of the page is either less than 1180 pixels or more than 1181 pixels?

Perhaps I am using this method incorrectly?

Comment: There is no such property in css with name "visibility" (If it is, then idk) and if you want to hide the element, use the css's property "display". Therefore, use "display = none" instead of "visibility. = none". And if you want to show, use "display = block"

Comment: your code should go inside a resize listener

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to reload the page, you can simply add a `resize` event listener to the window and apply your styles when the page is resized.

```js
const toggleMenu = document.querySelector('.toggle-menu');

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  console.log('resize event fired');

  if(window.innerWidth >= '1180') {
    toggleMenu.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  };

  if(window.innerWidth <= '1180'){
    toggleMenu.style.visibility = 'visible';
  };
});
```

It's also worth mentioning that you don't need to use JavaScript to do this, a [CSS Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) will do the job. The following CSS will achieve the same and has better performance.

```css
.toggle-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

@media (min-width: 1180px) {
  .toggle-menu {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and add all this conditions inside that. After that you need add the event listener for `onload` and `resize`. No need of called `window.reload` method.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", commonResizeLoad);
window.addEventListener("load", commonResizeLoad);

function commonResizeLoad(e) {
 if(window.innerWidth >= '1180') {
   toggleMenu.style.visibility = 'hidden';
 }
 if(window.innerWidth <= '1180'){
   toggleMenu.style.visibility = 'visible';
 }
}
```

Above I have used the common function. You can use different function if you want to apply different behavior.